# Android: Scaling drawables relative to a fixed size canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, android-drawable, dpi

I'm trying to create a custom bitmap at a predefined size, that will contain some Drawables and other graphic elements.

Canvas is the method i use, but i have a problem with some drawables size.

When i load a drawable, Android scales it to match the phone DPI, so i can't just draw it to the canvas since it will be too big.
I need to resize that drawable to fit my canvas correctly.

```
    ImageView ivIcon = new ImageView(mContext);
    ivIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_image);
    ivIcon.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    ivIcon.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(50, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(50, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)); // tried out some values and 50 seems to be OK.
    ivIcon.layout(0, 0, ivIcon.getMeasuredWidth(), ivIcon.getMeasuredHeight());
    ivIcon.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Log.d("TEST","Icon Size Before W="+ivIcon.getWidth() + " H="+ivIcon.getHeight());
    Bitmap iconBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap(ivIcon.getDrawingCache());
    Log.d("TEST","Icon Size After W="+iconBitmap.getWidth() + " H="+iconBitmap.getHeight());
    ivIcon.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    canvas.drawBitmap(iconBitmap, pos_X, pos_Y, null);
```

this solution works but i need it to be generic with canvas size as input.

How do i scale my elements correctly?

One more issue i have is setting a font size on a textview drawn into the same canvas.
i'm using this code to set the size:

```
LayoutInflater inf = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
RelativeLayout rlCursorTempTag = (RelativeLayout) inf.inflate(R.layout.layout_tag, null);
TextView tvTempTag = (TextView) rlCursorTempTag.findViewById(R.id.textView_temp);
tvTempTag.setText(sTemperature);
Typeface my_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),"fonts/browa.ttf");
tvTempTag.setTextSize(13);
tvTempTag.setTypeface(my_font);
```

But the font seems different on every device..

Thanks for you help.

Note:
My goal is saving an image to phone memory from elements i dynamically create (not shown on the screen) 
This is the image i'm trying to create on the canvas:
[image: Desired bitmap to be saved]

Comment: what do you need `iconBitmap` for?

Comment: Hi pskink. 
I'm drawing iconBitmap onto the canvas later on.

Comment: so you dont need that `Bitmap` at all: draw on your `Canvas` directly

Comment: can you please explain how will it solve the problem?
I mean i could use

Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.foobar);
d.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
d.draw(canvas);

but will it solve the scaling problem?

Comment: honestly there is a big mess over here, you use `ImageView`, drawing cache, you `measure` it but never use? what actually is your goal?

Comment: Maybe i didn't phase my question well :\
My goal is saving an image to phone memory from elements i dynamically create (not shown on the screen).

Comment: so it is something like `LayerDrawable` ?

Comment: I've uploaded an image of what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92383/discussion-between-alon-and-pskink).